Postgresql Query vs View execution speed issue
I have a few tables that I join to produce a result data set I need (as shown below).
Query:
    select distinct on (e."Col1", e."Col2")
        s."SrcId",
        s."CreatedTime",
        s."ColM",
        s."ColN",
        m."ColX" as "m_ColX",
        m."ColY" as "m_ColY",
        n."ColZ1" as "n.ColZ1",
        n."ColZ2" as "n.ColZ2",
        e."Col1",
        e."Col2"
    from schema1."Table1" s
    left join schema1."Table2" e on s."SrcId" = e.sid and date_trunc('second',s."CreatedTime")=date_trunc('second',e."ReportedTime")
    left join schema1."Table3" m on m."Sid"=s."SrcId" and m."IsActive"=TRUE
    left join schema1."Table4" n on n."Sid"=s."SrcId" and n."IsActive"=TRUE;

When I execute the query directly with a where clause (shown below), the results are almost instantaneous.
select distinct on (e."Col1", e."Col2")
        s."SrcId",
        s."CreatedTime",
        s."ColM",
        s."ColN",
        m."ColX" as "m_ColX",
        m."ColY" as "m_ColY",
        n."ColZ1" as "n.ColZ1",
        n."ColZ2" as "n.ColZ2",
        e."Col1",
        e."Col2"
    from schema1."Table1" s
    left join schema1."Table2" e on s."SrcId" = e.sid and date_trunc('second',s."CreatedTime")=date_trunc('second',e."ReportedTime")
    left join schema1."Table3" m on m."Sid"=s."SrcId" and m."IsActive"=TRUE
    left join schema1."Table4" n on n."Sid"=s."SrcId" and n."IsActive"=TRUE
    where s."SrcId"=10 and s."CreatedTime" between '2024-10-10T00:00:00.000Z' and '2024-10-10T10:10:10.000Z'

But if I use the same query in a view, the results take way longer.
Assume the view is called view1 for simplicity and I invoke it as below:
select * from schema1.view1 where "SrcId"=10 and "CreatedTime" between '2024-10-10T00:00:00.000Z' and '2024-10-10T10:10:10.000Z'

Can someone point out why this is the case and if there is anything I can do to improve/optimize calling the view so it results in a similar performance?
The first thought that comes to mind is the view might be taking time to correlate the where clause fields with the fields in the actual tables to figure out which ones to map them to. Could that be the culprit (or worse could that be skewing my results as well?) If so, what is a more efficient way to pass the where clause?

hello, can you share the plan of both queries, for example: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) your_query

Offtopic: You are aware that DISTINCT ON without an ORDER BY can give you some sort of random results?
Ontopic: We need a query plan and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved.

Plus, obviously, your version of Postgres. More importantly, your query on the view cannot work at all, because neither "SrcId" nor "CreatedTime" are in the SELECT list of the view. Please fix your question.

Anthony, I did not understand what you mean by the plan of the queries. These are to be called from a DotNet API. Obviously a view is much easier to handle here than a query (I'm told by the dotnet team that custom queries are not really the way to go with the code unless absolutely necessary).

Frank, thanks for the pointer. For now, I removed distinct on from the query, but will keep this in mind when I use it. I am yet to google what a query plan is. But will post it next time on. Thank you.

Erwin, Our version of Postgres is PostgreSQL 15.7 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit (on AWS RDS).
I missed showing the fields in the select here, but they were present in the original query. I updated the question with them. Thank you.

The queries are not equivalent:

in the query that runs fast for you, the WHERE condition is executed before the DISTINCT, and it can probably filter rows efficiently

in the slow query, the WHERE condition is applied after the DISTINCT, which prevents such filtering and may give you a different query result


My recommendation is to lay off the DISTINCT in the view definition. If you really need it, write it into the query that uses the view.

Thank you Laurenz. This definitely looks like issue. When I removed distinct from the query, the repsonse times are within a few milliseconds of each other. Thank you for the explaining the difference.
